# Bind WPF Command to ViewModel property in C# XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to build a generic `Command` that can access properties from my `ViewModel`. On my Window are several `TextBoxes`, each `TextBox`has a `Button` next to it. When the `Button` is clicked I show an `OpenFileDialog` and set the `Text` of the `TextBox` to the selected files path. The `TextBox`itself has a `Binding` to a property in the `ViewModel`. Currently this is implemented with a `Command` in the `ViewModel`. The `Buttons` all call the same `Command`but each `Button` has a its property `CommandParameter` set to the `TextBox` that will receive the filepath. The drawback of this is, that I need to cast the parameter from the `Command`execution to a `TextBox` and then set its `Text`property. My question is now, if I can't somehow bind my 'Command' to the same property the `TextBox`is bound to. Here is what I currently do:

**XAML**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SettingsPath}" x:Name="txtSettingsPath"></TextBox>
<Button Command="{Binding OpenFile}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtSettingsPath}">...</Button>
```

**C#**

```
public ICommand OpenFile
{
    get
    {
        bool CanExecuteOpenFileCommand()
        {
            return true;
        }

        CommandHandler GetOpenFileCommand()
        {
            return new CommandHandler((o) =>
            {
                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                ofd.Multiselect = false;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SettingsPath) && File.Exists(settingsPath))
                {
                    ofd.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(SettingsPath);
                }

                if(ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    if(o is TextBox txt)
                    {
                        txt.Text = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                }

            }, CanExecuteOpenFileCommand);
        }

        return GetOpenFileCommand();
    }
}
```

In the XAML I would like to have something like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SettingsPath}"></TextBox>
<Button Command="{Binding OpenFile}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding SettingsPath}">...</Button>
```

Comment: Can you not use the XAML you posted, then just do o = ofd.FileName ?

Comment: What you want is a small viewmodel, call it `SettingsPathSelectorViewModel`, that has a `Path` property and an `OpenFile` command. Then you'd write a DataTemplate that looks like your last XAML snippet to display it. You could then have your main viewmodel expose a few `SettingsPathSelectorViewModel`s

Comment: @Milney Unfortunately not. `o` is just the string in that case, not a reference to the property.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. How do I display the controls? Could you provide a little sample?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé Working one up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I was talking about in comments:

The "little viewmodel". I added a `Label` property because in my test project, they all looked the same. That doesn't have to be part of this viewmodel.

```
public class SettingsPathSelectorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Label Property
    private String _label = default(String);
    public String Label
    {
        get { return _label; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _label)
            {
                _label = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion Label Property

    #region SettingsPath Property
    private String _settingsPath = null;
    public String SettingsPath
    {
        get { return _settingsPath; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _settingsPath)
            {
                _settingsPath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion SettingsPath Property


    public ICommand OpenFile
    {
        get
        {
            bool CanExecuteOpenFileCommand()
            {
                return true;
            }

            //  We're no longer using the parameter, since we now have one                 
            //  command per SettingsPath. 
            CommandHandler GetOpenFileCommand()
            {
                return new CommandHandler((o) =>
                {
                    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                    ofd.Multiselect = false;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SettingsPath) && System.IO.File.Exists(SettingsPath))
                    {
                        ofd.InitialDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(SettingsPath);
                    }

                    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
                    {
                        SettingsPath = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                }, o => CanExecuteOpenFileCommand());
            }

            return GetOpenFileCommand();
        }
    }
}
```

A quickie main viewmodel for demo purposes. We'll illustrate two different ways you could expose these things: Either as named properties, or a collection of varying size displayed in an `ItemsControl`.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SettingsPathSelectorViewModel FirstPath { get; } = new SettingsPathSelectorViewModel() { Label = "First Path" };
    public SettingsPathSelectorViewModel SecondPath { get; } = new SettingsPathSelectorViewModel() { Label = "Second Path" };

    public ObservableCollection<SettingsPathSelectorViewModel> SettingsPaths { get; } = new ObservableCollection<SettingsPathSelectorViewModel>
    {
        new SettingsPathSelectorViewModel() { Label = "First Collection Path" },
        new SettingsPathSelectorViewModel() { Label = "Second Collection Path" },
        new SettingsPathSelectorViewModel() { Label = "Third Collection Path" },
    };
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SettingsPathSelectorViewModel}">
        <!-- GroupBox and Label are optional -->
        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Label}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding SettingsPath}" />
                <Button 
                    Content="..." 
                    Command="{Binding OpenFile}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    MinWidth="40" 
                    Margin="4,0,0,0" 
                    />
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding FirstPath}" />
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding SecondPath}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl
            ItemsSource="{Binding SettingsPaths}"
            />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here's what I mean about omitting `Label` and the `GroupBox`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SettingsPathSelectorViewModel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SettingsPath}" />
            <Button 
                Content="..." 
                Command="{Binding OpenFile}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                MinWidth="40" 
                Margin="4,0,0,0" 
                />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label>First Path</Label>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding FirstPath}" />
        <Label>Second Path</Label>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SecondPath}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Wow! That's a cool and clean solution. I'm an absolute WPF (and MVVM) newbie and amazed with the possibilities! Thank you very much!

Comment: @RomanoZumbé It gets really fun once you work your way up the learning curve a bit.