# Set default value in XAML if binding is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

**EDIT**

This is no duplicate of a fallback for string null values. I'm asking for a fallback for a complex type.

**Original question**

This is a followup question to a question I've asked yesterday:

[Bind WPF Command to ViewModel property in C# XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805620/bind-wpf-command-to-viewmodel-property-in-c-sharp-xaml)

The core part of the accepted answer to me was this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SettingsPathSelectorViewModel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SettingsPath}" />
            <Button 
                Content="..." 
                Command="{Binding OpenFile}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                MinWidth="40" 
                Margin="4,0,0,0" 
                />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label>First Path</Label>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding FirstPath}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

A `DataTemplate`is created for a custom type and then a `ContentControl` is bound to a property of that type.

The problem is now, that the property (`FirstPath` in the example) could be `null` and no UI elements are rendered. How could I accomplish to render the controls from the `DataTemplate` even if the property is `null`

As Evk suggested I've implemented a Converter:

```
public class PathSelectorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object o, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return o ?? new PathSelector();
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object o, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return o ?? new PathSelector();
    }
}
```

I've added an instance of the converter a resource in my window:

```
<view:PathSelectorConverter x:Key="pathSelectorConverter"/>
```

And added it in the binding to the property:

But the converter is only called if the value is not null

Comment: Can't you ensure that it is never null instead?

Comment: @Evk Unfortunately not. I have a list of elements you can select from and each element has a `FirstPath` property. If the elements List is empty I have this undesired behavior.

Comment: Then you can use a converter which will return some default instance of SettingsPathSelectorViewModel if provided value is null.

Comment: @Evk Do you have a link to a description of such a converter?

Comment: @Evk I've found a description for an converter, but it is not working. I've edited my question with the code I've added for the converter. Perhaps you have an idea.

Comment: And what if use `TargetNullValue` of binding?

Comment: @Evk I tried it by putting a dummy property to my ViewModel and set it for TargetNullValue, but didn't work

Comment: @RomanoZumbé You should add your solution as an actual answer, you are allowed to answer your own questions.

Comment: @BradleyUffner you're right. Done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826371/use-a-complex-type-for-xaml-binding-fallbackvalue/44826771#44826771) of mine (The code is from Clemens):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <model:PathSelector x:Key="FallbackPathSelector" />
</Window.Resources>
...

<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyPathSelector,
                          FallbackValue={StaticResource FallbackPathSelector}}"/>
```