# Use a complex type for XAML Binding FallBackValue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I was searching for a way to bind a UI element to a complex type and have another complex type as `FallBackValue`. Unfortunately I didn't find anything on that topic. When I set `FallBackValue` to the name of a property or a type it is always displayed as a `string` :

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyPathSelector, FallbackValue=model:PathSelector}"/>
```

In this case the string

> model:PathSelector

will be displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case you want to avoid tag syntax, or use the same fallback object for multiple bindings, you may use a resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <model:PathSelector x:Key="FallbackPathSelector" />
</Window.Resources>
...

<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyPathSelector,
                          FallbackValue={StaticResource FallbackPathSelector}}"/>
```

Comment: This solution is so much better than mine. Thanks!

Comment: Not better in general. In case you need a distinct fallback object for each binding, tag syntax is simpler.

Comment: Thats true. But in my case I need it just for UI rendering. With your solution I save a lot of boilerplate code, since there are a lot of these controls.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the binding in tag syntax instead of attribute syntax and there I could reference the complex tape:

```
<ContentControl>
     <ContentControl.Content>
           <Binding Path="MyPathSelector">
               <Binding.FallbackValue>
                    <model:PathSelector />
               </Binding.FallbackValue>
           </Binding>
      </ContentControl.Content>
</ContentControl>
```